# handle or block desktop switching

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, native

While starting the application, a new desktop is opened first and I can run the application in the given path on this new desktop. After a while the application is opened, the default desktop opens again. My guess is that another application is performing the return to the default desktop.

```
void securitycontextnamespace::process(char* desktopName, Napi::String startApplicationPath)
{
    STARTUPINFOA starti;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION proci;
    char cmdArgs[] = " ok ok ";
    
    ZeroMemory( &starti, sizeof(starti) );
    starti.cb = sizeof(starti);
    ZeroMemory( &proci, sizeof(proci) );
    
    const char *appPath = startApplicationPath.Utf8Value().c_str();

    LPSTR lpstrDesktop = const_cast<LPSTR>(desktopName);
    starti.lpDesktop = lpstrDesktop;
    
    HDESK secure_desktop = OpenDesktopA(lpstrDesktop, NULL, FALSE, GENERIC_ALL);
    
    if( !CreateProcessA(appPath, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &starti, &proci)) 
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "Process Started.\n");
        SwitchDesktop(secure_desktop);
        //wait until created process is closed
        WaitForSingleObject(proci.hProcess, INFINITE );
        CloseHandle(proci.hProcess );
        CloseHandle(proci.hThread );
    }
}


void securitycontextnamespace::cdesktpo(char* desktopName, Napi::String startApplicationPath){
    LPSTR lpstrDesktop = const_cast<LPSTR>(desktopName);
    
    HDESK original_desktop = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES securityAttributes = {0};
    securityAttributes.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    securityAttributes.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    securityAttributes.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    HDESK hDesk=CreateDesktopA(lpstrDesktop, 0, 0, DF_ALLOWOTHERACCOUNTHOOK, DESKTOP_READOBJECTS | 
                                        DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW | 
                                        DESKTOP_CREATEMENU | 
                                        DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL | 
                                        DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD | 
                                        DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK | 
                                        DESKTOP_ENUMERATE | 
                                        DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS | 
                                        DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP |                                         
                                        STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE | 
                                        WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS | 
                                        WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS, &securityAttributes);
    SetThreadDesktop(hDesk);
    
    if(hDesk!=NULL) {
        securitycontextnamespace::process(desktopName, startApplicationPath);
        CloseDesktop(hDesk);
        
        SwitchDesktop(original_desktop);
        SetThreadDesktop(original_desktop);
    }
    else {
        printf( "CreateDesktop failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        SwitchDesktop(original_desktop);
        SetThreadDesktop(original_desktop);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to prevent and handle reverting to the default desktop?

Comment: It seems a rather inconsistent expectation to want to both be able to call `SwitchDesktop` with the desired effect, and allow arbitrary applications to prevent `SwitchDesktop` from having the desired effect.

Comment: this is an exam application and it have to be secure. because of this I want to prevent other application desktop switch

Comment: That's understood. But if *you* can block desktop switching, then so can anyone else. Which would put your code into a situation where it won't be able to switch to a different desktop altogether. Though I cannot think of a situation where the visibility of any given desktop were a vital part of security.

Comment: Correct. Do you have any idea?